# Slow boot after update, XHCI_HCD problems

Tags: boot, usb, xhci-hcd

I updated to 16.04 the other day and my boot time has gotten really slow. I am dual booting on a Macbook Pro using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). Judging from the dmesg output I think this is a problem with the xhci_hcd driver. I've seen a few places where people have this same problem but I come across any resolutions yet.

Here is some relevant info:

```
➜  ~ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 4, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 5, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=bcm5974, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 4, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

relevant dmesg portions:

```
                     ............

[    6.651769] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   11.664027] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[   11.664030] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   11.868052] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[   16.672349] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   16.672377] usb 1-3: hub failed to enable device, error -62

                 ......

[   22.464663] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   27.680953] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[   27.680956] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   27.884988] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[   38.481586] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[   38.481590] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   43.697916] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   43.901909] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 4, error -62

                       .........
```

and kernel version

```
➜  ~ uname -r
4.4.0-22-generic
```

Comment: What happen if you try to load with a older kernel ? is it still slow ?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem.

Comment: @rabin 14.04 works without a problem.